# Look for a VBA/VB parser/compiler written in OCaml

Tags: vb.net, parsing, vba, compiler-construction, ocaml

I am planning to write a compiler (including parser) in `OCaml` to parse and run `VBA` or/and `VB` programs. I have done this for simple imperative languages, but I am not sure how to handle the "object" features of `VBA` or/and `VB`...

Does anyone know if there is any existing work that I can inspire?

Comment: Good parsers for various (especially legacy) languages (e.g., VBA/VB6/VB.net) are hard to find in general.  Why constrain it by insisting on a particular (not widely used) programming langauge?   I have answers if OCaml isn't a requirement.

Comment: @IraBaxter Actually OCaml is more or less a requirement, but what answers do you have?

Comment: And why is OCaml a requirement?  Nobody running the final compiled programs cares.  My guess is that you just like OCaml.

Comment: Well, that is because because people around me like OCaml...

Answer (score 5):

Not an OCaml solution (but OP asked):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is general purpose program analysis and transformation machinery.  It is intended to be a convenient foundation for custom software engineering tools for computer languages, with the goal being to help the tool engineer get his job done, rather than spending his time reinventing the wheel.  In particular, many people think that getting a parser is the big part of the job.  This is simply false.  See [Life After Parsing](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html).

DMS has [production front ends](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds) for many languages, both modern and legacy, including [Visual Basic](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/VisualBasicFrontEnd.html) in its variety of dialects (VB6, VBA [essentially the same as VB6]) and VB.net.

By production I mean have been applied to real code systems of significant size and handle all the corresponding parsing issues.  This is pretty hard for legacy languages, e.g., VB, especially the older dialects because such languages are generally poorly documented (VB6 and VBA especially so). The only way to get this right is to build a draft parser, run it against reality, and revise until lots of code goes through sensibly.   This often takes longer than doing the draft parser because it isn't easy to understand the errors (they're undocumented!), you have to decide if they are real or the code base just has junk (more often than you'd think), guess what it means for the grammar and try it all again.

These front ends as a minimum parse source code and build ASTs; they can also invert this process to regenerate *legal* compilable code with the comments back as source text files.  The VisualBasic front ends do this. Some of our other front ends (C, C++, Java, COBOL)  go further: name/type resolution, flow analysis, etc.; they do that by collecting key program facts from the language-specific AST and then apply DMS-supplied machinery to compute the results.  This would be possible for VisualBasic, too, if such facts were useful.

Comment: Thanks... What interests me most is the front end for VB, if I understand well, I can connect the ASTs built by your tool to my analyzer (in OCaml), right? Also, your tool is paid, right?

Comment: DMS and its front ends are commercial tools, yes.  Contact the company for details.   "Can connect the ASTs to your analyzer..."  Yes, we get that question a lot.  And yes, we can export the ASTs in either a lisp like notation or as an XML tree (frankly, neither of these tasks is difficult if you have an AST data structure).  But then you'll need to read it, and proceed to build your own machinery to process it to achieve your purpose.  Yes, that's possible.  Did you read my essay on life after parsing? You get to replicate as much of that as need to acheive your purpose, ....

Comment: ... and that's usually *tons* more work than people expect, especially if they haven't done it before.  We won't stop you from doing this, but the actual level of effort required and the amount of details usually prevents people from getting to their goal.  We offer DMS as an integrated package of the typically machinery you need to implement complex code analysis and transformation tasks.  We have some 50 man-years of PhD level engineering in it, driven by experience as to what people need and feedback.   Your move.

Answer (score 1):

For an example of a tiny OO language written in OCaml check out the source code for boa at: http://andrej.com/plzoo/.

The OO flavour is not class based though so I'm not sure how useful it will be.